# Sort an array object containing activerecord query results using sort method in reverse order (DESC)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, object, activerecord

I have an array object `@questions` which is a collection of two Active record query results based on two conditions. **@questions** have a set of questions along with their attributes. I want to sort it in descending order only by using **sort** method based on one of its attribute `created_at`.

Please help to get that work :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

There is a ruby way of doing it on array object @questions.

```
@questions = @questions.sort { |value1, value2| value2.created_at <=> value1.created_at }
```

The above just works fine for me.

Comment: @questions is not ActivRecord object, it's an Array.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
@questions = Question.order("created_at desc")
```

Comment: No, @questions is a collection of two query results. So I need to sort the object using sort method, not using AR query

Comment: try this    `@questions = @questions.sort{|q1,q2| q2.created_at <=> q1.created_at}`